# trying to get data from external php file

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

what's wrong with this code of mine... I'm new to jquery especially 1.5 ver....

```
function loadQry(str)
{
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "fillpage.php",
          data: "prodcode="+str,
          success: function(response_data){
                     $('s_content').html(response_data)
                   }
          });
}
```

The problem I have is that, it's not returning any data from the external php. I'm confused..

In 1.4 using XMLHttpRequest I can do it and it's doing fine. but this code certainly bugged me LOT..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadPostQry(str) { 
    $.get( 'fillpage.php','prodcode='+str, function(data) { 
        $('#s_content').html(data); 
    },
    "html" ); 
}
```

I'm assuming you meant this?

Comment: I changed the function parameter in case you didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery version 1.5, [please read the updated jQuery Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to get familiar with jqXHR object:

> As of jQuery 1.5, the success callback
>   function is also passed a "jqXHR"
>   object (in jQuery 1.4, it was passed
>   the XMLHttpRequest object)

The docs also give you an example code using jqXHR.

`$.get` now has slightly modified interface:

```
jQuery.get( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ], [ dataType ] )
```

Comment: i been there, and i got some idea, but applying it, the stuff won't work. that's why I post this question to get some idea from the likes of yours whom I guessed had enough knowledge with this one...

Comment: just to be clear ... what status code does the server respond with? Does it respond at all? Can you tell us what do you actually want to return from the server?

Comment: I already got the code running, thanks for your time.. It has todo with the function parameter and the # element id.

Comment: No problem, glad to see it working :)

now since I see you're new to stackoverflow, you can check jerluc's answer as final and upvote it. Just the way of saying 'thanks' around here ;)